# Unable to get real remote IP in AKS with advanced networking

Tags: nginx, networking, kubernetes, azure-aks

We have two AKS clusters for different environments. Both use a Nginx server as a custom ingress. By that I mean that it acts like an ingress, but it is just a normal Nginx deployment behind a service. There are several good reasons for that setup, the main one being that ingress did not exist in AKS when we started.

The services are defined like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <our name>
  namespace: <our namespace>
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: <our app>
  loadBalancerIP: <our ip>
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

We have configured Nginx with the real ip module like this:

```
real_ip_header X-Original-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8; # or whatever ip is correct
```

One environment uses the old basic networking, networkPlugin=kubenet. There Nginx logs the real client IP addresses in the log and can use them for access controls. The other uses advanced networking, networkPlugin=azure. There Nginx logs the IP address of one of the nodes, which is useless. Both the X-Original-Forwarded-For and the standard X-Forwarded-For headers are empty and of course the source IP is from the node, not from the client.

Is there a way around this? If at all possible we would like to avoid defining a "real" ingress as our own Nginx server contains custom configuration that would be hard to duplicate in such a setup, plus it is not clear that a standard ingress would help either?

Comment: I don't know which version of Kubernetes you are using right now, but it seems that Microsoft fixed the problem 5 days ago : https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/607

Comment: We're in contact with support and they talked about that. Unfortunately not clear if the fix applies to us as we are not using a true ingress, their advice is to use custom iptables rules similar to the ones in the issue for now. I'll keep you posted when we get something that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft should have fixed this by now for real ingresses. However, apparently the fix doesn't cover our case where Nginx runs as a pod behind a service with advanced networking. We were told to use the workaround posted by denniszielke in https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/607 where the iptables for all nodes are updated regularly. Quite dirty in my view, but it works.

We still have the service defined as above with "externalTrafficPolicy: Local" and we have installed the ConfigMap and DaemonSet from the link. I changed the script to reduce logging a bit and moved both to another namespace.